# Deleting Section in UITableview Crashing App

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

I have a UITableView and I want to delete the sections and rows. I am trying to delete the whole section with its rows inside it. Following are the cases which is confusing for me.

1. When I try to delete section from top to bottom or from bottom to top in order all sections gets deleted without error
2. When I try to delete sections in random i.e first I delete top first section and then when I try to delete 4th or 8th or last section the app crashes its own

**Crash Log**

> Fatal error: Index out of range

here is how I am doing it:

```
 func onHeaderSwippedRight(ClickedSection: IndexPath) {


    dataSource.remove(at: ClickedSection.section)

    // use the UITableView to animate the removal of this row
    tableView.beginUpdates()

    tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet.init(integer : ClickedSection.section), with: .automatic)

    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

> The Index path that I am passing into this function **onHeaderSwippedRight(ClickedSection: IndexPath)** is passwed by delegated method. Bcz In my Class I am passing it while setting up my data of section

**A raw guess of mine is that after removing the section tableview must update the indices of the section, because as I am removing data from data source it must not get Index out of bound issue if sections gets update themselves**

please help and tell me what I am doing wrong

**Update;**

```
public class ListModel : Object {


var   Id : String = ""
var   UserId : Int64 = 0
var   Name : String? = ""
var   Items : [ListDetailServiceModel]? =  []}
```

> This is my model, and I am having list of this like so

```
let dataSource :[ListModel] = []
```

Comment: Put breakpoint in the beginning of that method and add info here about ClickedSection, dataSource.count and tableView numberOfSections call.

Comment: have you tried updating number of section after deleting ?

Comment: @Tobi how to update them ?

Comment: @kirander I did this, it looks like ClickedSections not updating after deletion of sections

Comment: can you show full code of tableview delegates and data srouce

Comment: In data source, I have List of custom model , that model contains another list of custom model. Its simple

Comment: I asked to update your post with info I wrote in previous message.

Comment: index out of range could be a data srouce problem  but we can't see any in code , you deleted a section so the problem might be around there

Comment: check updated post, if you need any thing more just let me know